# vscode tasks.json transform pickfile

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have next vscode tasks.json

```json
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${userHome}/build.py",
        "args": ["param_def=${input:pickBuild}"]
    }
],
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickBuild",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile",
      "args": {
        "include": "**/default_*.py",
        "description": "Select build",
        "display": "fileName",
      }
    }
]}
```

**when run:**

**actual:** `/home/user/build.py param_def=/home/user/default_android.py`

**expected:** `/home/user/build.py param_def=default_android`

P.S: I have tried use `extension.commandvariable.transform`, but did not success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following config  in your `tasks.json`

```json
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${userHome}/build.py",
        "args": ["param_def=${input:pickBuild}"]
    }
],
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickBuild",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${pickFile:build}",
        "find": "^.*/(.*).py",
        "replace": "$1",
        "pickFile": {
          "build": {
            "include": "**/default_*.py",
            "description": "Select build",
            "display": "fileName",
          }
        }
      }
    }
]}
```

Comment: do you know how can I use exclude? for example if I would like next exclude "exclude": "**/{default_keyboard_*.py, default_mouse_*.py}", I have tried, but it does not work as I meant.

Comment: @FelX3 try `*/default_{keyboard_,mouse_}*.py`

Comment: no, same output, it only excludes default_keyboard

Comment: @FelX3 maybe the known problem (see doc page) also applies to Linux

Comment: @FelX3 What if you swap `keyboard` and `mouse`? Are the mouse files not excluded?

Comment: if I swipe it, only mouse will be excluded. maybe you are right, LInux also have same issue

Comment: it worked, I had a space keyboard_, mouse_, when removed space keyboard_,mouse_ it worked. by the way the form that worked 
"exclude": "**/default_{keyboard_\*,mouse_\*}"

Thanks a lot

Comment: @FelX3 why put a `*` inside `{}` if you put a `*` after `}`

Comment: it is the same, yes